# newenvironment behaving differently inside another environment

Tags: beamer, environments, tcolorbox

Friends,

Please have a look at the code below.
The problem is the environment `hlcard` is behaving differently when it is inside `card` environment, or directly under `frame`. I have picked the card environment directly from net, and doesn't have much clue what those long optional argument is doing. Kindly help.

The behaivour directly inside `frame` is the expected behaviour

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{3F51B5}
\definecolor{BGgrey03}{RGB}{190,190,190}
\definecolor{BGgrey04}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\tcbset{%
colback=BGgrey04, colbacktitle=dcol, coltitle=white, coltext=dcol,%
enhanced, sharpish corners=all,%
fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!BGgrey03}, % top
fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!BGgrey03}, % bottomSmall
fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!BGgrey03}, % bottomBig
left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,%
title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
segmentation code={\path[draw=BGgrey01](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}%
}

\newenvironment{card}[1][pR23s2OTKY]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{pR23s2OTKY}}{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}%
    }{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colbacktitle=dcol, coltitle=white, title=#1, left=1mm, right=6mm, top=1mm,
        bottom=1mm, middle=4mm, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm, ]%
    }%
}{%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newenvironment{hlcard}[1][pR23s2OTKY]{%
      \begin{tcolorbox}[noparskip, breakable, colback=dcol,%
          coltitle=black,coltext=white, fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, left=1mm, right=6mm, top=1mm,
        bottom=1mm, middle=4mm, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,]%
}{%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{card}[Problem]
  \begin{hlcard}
    Foo
  \end{hlcard}
\end{card}
  \begin{hlcard}
    Bar
  \end{hlcard}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're nesting `tcolorbox` environments -- so why should `hlcard` look the same inside or outside of the box `card`, concerning skipping coming from `card`? Why are you using `\newenvironment` at all when you can use the better suited `\newtcolorbox` macro? Also gluing contents from the net together to something what 'might' work is not a very well-designed strategy

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. The reason behind not using `\newtcolorbox` is very simple...I was not aware of it. I have moved both the `\newenvironment` to `\newtcoorbox`. Thanks a lot for this.
But, about the main problem: when it is nested, I can't find why in nested env, its getting the dark border at all. Can you kindly help?

Comment: The nested boxes are 'reset', so they are using some default values or the ones explicitly with `\tcbset`, which is the common 'pool' of options for all `tcolorboxes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\tcbset` macro provides for `.style` options, i.e. collections of specific `tcolorbox` (or `tikz/pgfkeys`), otherwise any option that is not 'wrapped' in a `.style` is used globally and has a side effect on `tcolorbox` 'layers'

Nested boxes are `reset`, using a default setting and the global values from `tcbset`.

I suggest to use an `outerlayer` style and an `innerlayer` style which calls `outerlayer` first, then applies its own settings.

Also the `environments` should be defined with `\newtcolorbox` instead of wrapping them in `\newenvironment` macros.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}
\RequirePackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{dcol}{HTML}{3F51B5}
\definecolor{BGgrey03}{RGB}{190,190,190}
\definecolor{BGgrey04}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% Common options
\tcbset{%
  left=6mm, right=6mm, top=6mm, bottom=6mm, middle=4mm,
}

\tcbset{
  outerlayer/.style={
    enhanced,
    sharpish corners=all,
    colbacktitle=dcol, 
    coltitle=white, 
    left=1mm, 
    right=6mm, 
    top=1mm,
    bottom=1mm, 
    middle=4mm, 
    toptitle=1mm, 
    bottomtitle=1mm,
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{0.9mm}{0.6mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!BGgrey03}, % top
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.6mm}{-0.1mm}{0.2mm}{black!40!BGgrey03}, % bottomSmall
    fuzzy shadow={0mm}{-0.2mm}{-0.2mm}{0.2mm}{black!20!BGgrey03}, % bottomBig
    title filled, boxrule=0mm, %
    segmentation code={\path[draw=BGgrey01](segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
},
  innerlayer/.style={outerlayer,
    noparskip, 
    breakable, 
    colback=dcol,%
    coltitle=black,
    coltext=white, 
    fonttitle={\bfseries \scshape}, 
    bottomtitle=1mm}
}



\newtcolorbox{card}[1][]{%
  outerlayer,
  title=#1,
}


\newtcolorbox{hlcard}[1][]{%
  innerlayer,
  #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{card}[Problem]
  \begin{hlcard}
    Foo
  \end{hlcard}
\end{card}
\begin{hlcard}
  Bar
\end{hlcard}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]